# Z3py return unsupported operand using pow() function

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm new  in using Z3. I've been trying to solve a problem with Z3 but I can't. I've had a c/c++ code like this:

```
n4 = 0
if ( j1 != j6 )
    ++n4;
if ( j1 + 1 != j2 )
    ++n4;
if ( j4 + 1 != j1 )
    ++n4;
if ( j3 + 4 != j6 )
    ++n4;
if ( j5 + 2 != j3 )
    ++n4;
n5 = n4 + (j4 ^ 102) + j7;
```

`n5` variable must be greater than zero. The Z3py code that I've written is like below code:

```
for i in range(1,8):
    globals()['j%i' % i] = BitVec ('j%i' % i, 8)

s = Solver()
a = IntVector('a', 5)
a__1 = If(eq(j1, j6), 0, 1)
a__2 = If(j1+1 != j2, 1, 0)
a__3 = If(j4+1 != j1,1, 0)
a__4 = If(j3+4 != j6,1, 0)
a__5 = If(j5+2 != j3, 1,0)
su = IntVector('su',1)
su = Sum(a)
z= Real('z')
s.add(z == j4**102)
s.add(su + z + j7 > 0)

while s.check() == sat:
    print s.model()
```

After run script I got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'instance' and 'int'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number issues with the sample.
1. Bit-vectors don't support power operator. 
2. you compare reals and bit-vectors
3. It uses "eq", which is structural equality. You probably want semantic equality.

Comment: I'm not an expert in C/C++, but it seems to me like there is a translation problem here. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but... ) Are you sure `^` in C means power (Python `**`)? afaik `^` signifies exclusive-or operation (Python also `^`)

Comment: @stklik yeah, you're right. it's silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your actual question was, but I thought I'll translate the C(++) code the way I understand it.
I avoided the IntVector but used an Int to create the Sum.

I came up with the code below.
It does print models, I hope it's helping you out.

```
# import all of z3, because why not; define solver
from z3 import *
s = Solver()

# define j
for i in range(1,8):
    globals()['j%i' % i] = BitVec ('j%i' % i, 8)

# define 8-bit BitVector (BV) (not Integer in the mathematical sense)
n4 = BitVec('n4', 8)

# create an Int so we can use Sum (we could also create BV for each if and then sum directly)
su = Int("sum")
s.add(su == Sum(
            If(eq(j1, j6), 0, 1),
            If(j1+1 != j2, 1, 0),
            If(j4+1 != j1, 1, 0),
            If(j3+4 != j6, 1, 0),
            If(j5+2 != j3, 1, 0)
            )
     )
# we used an int, so we need to convert to a BV
s.add(n4 == Int2BV(su, 8))

# create n5 as an 8-bit BV and make sure it's value matches the formula
n5 = BitVec('n5', 8)
s.add(n5 == (n4 + (j4 ^ 102) + j7))  # I assume you meant ^ and not **
# requirement, n5 > 0 (could be merged with the lines above, avoiding the creation of n5 BV)
s.add(n5 > 0)

# iterate over solutions
while s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())  # Python3 uses brackets
```